# Position Chart in MVC View

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table at the top and now I want to display a chart at the bottom of the page. I have tried everything but the chart would not position. It always stays on top of everything and hides my table which is at the top.

```
var myChart = new Chart(width: 400, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Interest Payments")
    .AddSeries(
                name: "Interest",
                xValue: Model.nPer.ToString(),
                yValues: interest.ToString()
              )
    .Write();
```

I tried wrapping it around a div but that didn't work.

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: I am using bootstrap for my CSS and I don't have much html. I just have a table and now I want a chart at the bottom of my page